# Typescript - How to generate default data based on interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to generate default data based on interface definition?
Maybe we can have rule like boolean to be false, number to be zero, string to be empty, list to be one-element.

Assume I have a file named `some-definition.ts`:

```
export interface IOneInterface {
  fieldX: number;
  fieldY: string;
};

export interface IAnotherInterface {
  fieldM: number[];
  fieldN: string[];
};
```

I need a way to generate a json file `some-definition.json`:

```
{
  "IOneInterface": {
    "fieldX": 0,
    "fieldY": ""
  },
  "IAnotherInterface": {
    "fieldM": [0],
    "fieldN": [""]
  }
}
```

Comment: Those defaults for array types are not very trivial: the most conventional default array is an empty one. Can you state more information about your use case?

Comment: Try to use `class` instead of `interface`. This way you can assign default values to properties.